# C# - Properties.Settings.Default on Windows Startup

Tags: c#, winforms, startup, configuration-files

I have a C# program that runs on startup via an entry in `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. On startup, it seems that it can't read `Whatever.exe.config` (Settings file).

I'm aware that the "current dir" on boot is somewhere in `%windir%`. At the moment, I'm trying to load the config file by concatenating the config file name and `Application.ExecutablePath`, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

How do I use `Properties.Settings.Default` on Windows Startup?

**EDIT:** I'm on HKCU. I'm using `Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not load the file yourself and leave the paths alone**!

The Microsoft .NET settings mechanism does it all for you. The settings file will be automatically read when the application starts. And the user settings will be read from the user's profile.

What you didn't say is whether the application start through a user's registry entry (HKCU) or through the machine (HKLM). If you have user settings, they will be looked for in the current user's directory. That means that things may not work as expected when running the application with no used logged in.

Comment: Well, in that case .NET should be doing everything correctly out of the box without you fiddling with paths and loading the config file manually.